# How to take saturated portraits like these (with natural lighting)?

Tags: portrait, shooting-technique, reverse-engineering, saturation, natural-lighting

The photographer of these portraits claimed he used a 50mm f/1.8 prime with no special lighting equipment:

http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5163/5318756409_9f4ec94f5b_z.jpg

http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5008/5279497539_a2e4c326ce_z.jpg

No matter what I try I can't have the same saturation. The highlights in the models' eyes and on their lips are very difficult to achieve too. Any idea?

Here is one of my attempts:
[image]

Comment: He mentioned that some post-processing was done, but didn't say what. I suspect some photoshopping is needed to achieve this. What kind of editing should I be looking into?

Comment: I think the other photos have more saturated and vivid colors (albeit somewhat artificial).

Comment: If anything I'd say the example photos you are trying to emulate have desaturated colours, the example of yours looks much more saturated

Comment: @duysurfing, can you describe in different words what you mean by "saturated"? We were just discussing in chat how we'd like to see more questions along these lines, but that it's often so hard to capture the meaning in words. If you can try to elaborate I think we'll all benefit.

Comment: The linked images are heavily post-processed. It sometimes takes hours to tweak a single image just right. Also looks like the aperture is fully opened and lighting equipment was used.  Are you shooting at f1.8? Try applying some portrait colour effects, noise removal and sharpening..

Comment: @Jakub: The photo above was shot at f/2.8 because I was quite close to the model and was afraid that too shallow of a DOF might throw some part of her body out of focus. The ones I want to emulate were both taken at f/1.8 (that's what the photographer told me). Maybe this made a difference? Regarding the post-processing stuffs, what tutorials on the net would you recommend me to read? I'm pretty new to PP.

Comment: I think the default Lightroom effects might be a good start. You can choose say a bleach bypass effect and further tweak the settings with developing tools to learn how things work. The NIK plugins are great too; the Color Effex Pro by NIK has a bunch of specialized effects for portraits and its all integrated with Lightroom.  There are video tutorials for Lightroom yo can download that are pretty good. (Lynda.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can tell you how this was shot, assuming "no special lighting equipment" is true:

- Choose to shoot on an overcast day, or cloudy (but not dim) day.
- Shoot outdoor
- Have the model look straight or slightly up, so the top of her eye reflects the sky, giving the highlight

The lips are not that shinny unless you put some lip gloss on. So I think that is a different matter (its more about choosing the right makeup than lighting the model)

If you show us some of your attempted shots, we can observe your approach and let you know what should you change to achieve the result you want.

Edit: the attempted image you post is underexposed (arguably), and the white balance is off, giving a blueish tint. The hood also makes the light uneven, a good way to counter that would be to use a reflector. Lastly to get catch light you need a light source that is bright, small, placed high and inbetween you and your model. Sometimes you can use the sky if the angle is right, sometimes you can simply use something like a -2EV flash (on camera), or the catch-light card on dedicated external flash units like the 580EXII

Edit:
[image]
I edited your photo to illustrate what you can try.

Basically, you need to light your model's face **EVENLY**. Illustrated here is one way of doing it, using a fill flash. You can also use a reflector.

If you don't have an external flash, you can use internal flash, but the only way to control the direction of the light is to move the camera.

Finally, for even lighting, you need a lightsource of HUGE surface, that is CLOSE to the subject. In studios people use lights (softbox) as big as a dinning table to light a model's face. Basically, unless you are doing some special effects, you want soft light falling on your model's face. Bigger the light source, closing it is to the model = softer the light.

The key is to light the model with soft light across the face, showing the face in smooth shades. Not too flat, not too harsh, but **smooth**. Because that way the face looks three dimensional, thus is pleasing and natural.

Comment: I shot this one with the "nifty fifty" @f/2.8 on an overcast day (a little dim I guess). The model had her lip gloss on.

http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5169/5341897301_83ae0b7991_o_d.jpg

Comment: You link didn't work. Anyway I updated the answer to give you more info.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. Btw, what do you mean by -2EV flash? Can I do that with the popup flash of my 450D?

Comment: edited again to add info about "Fill Flash" , search it on google should give you good tutorials on how to use fill flash. internal flash can do it, but it is very limited.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading up on the Strobist stuffs per Nicholas' recommendation. I guess by "-2EV" you meant the power of the flash is 2 stop-down from full power, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, normally fill flash should be something around -1EV, but since the light from the tiny pop-up flash is very "straight-on" , I suggested -2EV instead to avoid very hard shadow.

Answer (score 1):

No special lighting equipment, or no lighting equipment at all? [cleared up].

It's controlled direct natural light, he'll be in an area where the light is quite naturally diffused but strong enough for punch, he's positioned the models in relation to where the light is falling naturally to emphasis and is probably getting a lot of help from reflective surfaces in the environment (especially for the catchlights in the first).

Also, if those are straight out of the camera he's played with the default image settings, to my eyes they look like they've been gently tweaked to achieve the results. The blacks, whites and colours all look like they've been lifted (the nifty is pretty contrasty at times but no where near that much) and massaged to get the image to where it is.

If you're struggling to do au natural then don't, look at going down the strobist route, it'll achieve a similar result.

Comment: He actually said "natural light only". He also mentioned some post-processing, but didn't say what.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for mentioning strobist. I'm reading up on it now. This community rocks.

Comment: I would say a lot of post processing. Personally, that is the first thing I saw when I clicked on your links. Colour effects filters or some colour tweaking, noise reduction and sharpening.

Answer (score 1):

To get the catchlight in the eyes in-camera you can:

1. Have the model look more to the direction of a light source (the sun if outdoors, a window if indoors, a normal light bulb or a flash will all work).
2. Use a reflector to shine some extra light into the eyes, anything light colored will do (white fabric, a piece of paper, a mirror, the wall of a near by building, etc.)

Just move the model and the reflector (and, if using artificial light the light source) around until you get a catchlight you like.

Obviously you can then make the catchlight more pronounced in post by brightening it, sharpening the eyes also sometimes helps.

Now, it looks to me like there are multiple catchlights in the picture you linked to (I'm not sure because those are small versions), this suggests multiple light sources were used to take the picture (or one light source + reflectors)